# Invalid identifier when adding foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to add foreign keys (in this case NSS_emp) to my tables and all of my attempts reflect the same error, invalid identifier in the () behind the foreign key, ive tried

```
ALTER TABLE Dependiente
ADD FOREIGN KEY(NSS_emp) REFERENCES Empleado;
```

also

```
ALTER TABLE Dependiente
ADD CONSTRAINT SH_1
FOREIGN KEY (NSS_emp) REFERENCES Empleado;
```

Ive tried a couple more and none are accepted

Comment: You can't just reference a table, you have to reference a column in that table `REFERENCES Empleado(someColumn)`

Answer (score 1):

First, you need the column in the *referenced* table:

```
ALTER TABLE Dependiente
    ADD CONSTRAINT SH_1
    FOREIGN KEY (NSS_emp) REFERENCES Empleado (NSS_Emp);
-----------------------------------------------^ or whatever
```

The column being referenced should be the primary key in `Empleado`.

Finally, the column `NSS_emp` also needs to exist in `Dependiente` and to have the same type as the referenced key in `Empleado`.